# how to use bat file to move files from subdirectories to one folder

Tags: batch-file, file-moving

I'm trying to use a .bat file to go into a folder, and take all photos within it and its subfolders, and place them all into another directory. I know how to copy the folder exactly, with all subfolders remaining in place when copied with

```
@ECHO OFF
XCOPY E:\FromFolderNameX C:\toFolderNameY /m /y
```

but I only want all of the photos to be in one folder in the end, no subfolders. Can this be done with a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I am assuming that you want to *copy* (not *move*) the photos from the subtree starting at `E:\FromFolderNameX` into the directory `C:\toFolderNameY`.
- I am assuming that by "photos" you mean `.jpg` files.
- The one-line interactive command is

  ```
  for /r E:\FromFolderNameX %p in (*.jpg) do copy /y "%~p" C:\ToFolderNameY
  ```
- If instead of JPG files you want to copy all files, just replace `*.jpg` with `*`.
- If instead of an interactive one liner you want a batch file, the core of the batch file would be

  ```
  for /r "%~1" %%p in (*.jpg) do copy "%%~p" "%~2"
  ```

(`%1` is the first positional argument = the top of the subtree from where you want to copy the files. `%2` is the second positional argument = the destination directory.)

In production, the batch file would probably check that the directories `%1` and `%2` exist and are really directories; and it should probably accept an optional third argument giving the pattern of the files to be copied.

Enter `for /?` to read more about [how `for /r` works](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html).

Comment: When I run that one-line interactive command, I get "~p C:\toFolderNameY was unexpected at this time."
What does the "%~p" do, and why is it giving me this error?
I did place that line into a bat file and ran it.

Comment: @BlakeThompson: I gave both the form for interactive use and the form for batch use. You cannot take the interactive form and put in a batch file; at a minimum, you need to change all `%` into `%%`.